# OpenId Connect to Google gives me Http 400

Tags: java, servlets, google-api, openid-connect

Im trying to access to Google APIs using OAuth 2.0

but i always receive the http 400 when i try to get the token

I'm using Tomcat8 with Java SDK 8
And i don't know what is wrong.

```
private void sendPost(
        final String code, 
        final String clientId, 
        final String clientSecret, 
        final String redirectUri,
        final String grantType) throws Exception {

    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

    StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();
    strb.append("code=" + code);
    strb.append("&client_id=" + clientId);
    strb.append("&client_secret=" + clientSecret);
    strb.append("&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri);
    strb.append("&grant_type=" + grantType);

    String urlParameters = strb.toString();

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(urlParameters.length()));


    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

My output is the following it seems that all parameters are ok.

```
Sending 'POST' request to URL : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
Post parameters : code=<code>.InoAg9JcLi0boiIBeO6P2m94pmoskwI&client_id=<clientid>.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=<secret>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/Oauth/connect&grant_type=authorization_code
Response Code : 400
```

Comment: Try reading the response message. Good APIs provide helpful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

1. you'd want to url-encode the parameters
2. I don't think Google supports redirect_uri's pointing to "localhost" anymore so that would suggest that you got the "code" on a different redirect_uri than the one presented on the token endpoint request